# Volley android remove div-container from fetched json

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, android-volley, wordpress-rest-api

I use volley to fetch content from a wordpress blog via its api.

The content I receive looks like this:

```
<p>Blog content blabla</p>\n
<div id=\ "pressrelease-link-345\"  class=\ "sh-link pressrelease-link sh-hide\">
  <a href=\ "#\" onclick=\ "showhide_toggle('pressrelease', 345, 'Show full article', 'Hide article'); return false;\" aria-expanded=\ "false\">
    <span id=\"pressrelease-toggle-345\">Show full article</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div id=\ "pressrelease-content-345\" class=\ "sh-content pressrelease-content sh-hide\" style=\ "display: none;\">
  </p>\n
  <p>more content which is displayed after expanding the text in the browser</p>
```

I'd like to show the full text in my app, so the whole -part should be removed. Is there a nicer way to do this than just building the string for each article (id, here 345)? I though maybe I could just 'filter' out the div using volley, but didn't figure out how yet.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand, you want remove a div from a HTML page with a WebView ?

```
private void yourwebv (){
    String url = "mysite.com";
    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WEBVIEW_ID);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    final ProgressBar ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
    ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            String javaScript ="javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('YOURDIVCLASSNAME_REMOVE')[0]" +
                    ".style.display='none';void(0);";
            webview.loadUrl(javaScript);
            Log.d("[WV]", " JS OK");

            final ProgressBar ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
            ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl(url);
    Log.d("[WV]", " WEBSITE + JS SCRIPT OK");
}
```